# SwiftUI Button Text width violates borders, not compressed by HStack

Tags: macos, button, swiftui, label, width

I have a small HStack with Text and a Button. This is limited with `maxWidth: 200`

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Some Text")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Text("A Very much to long button Text with more Text")
                    .truncationMode(.middle)
            })
        }.frame(maxWidth: 200)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

This ends up scaling the button even beyond the borders of the HStack.

[image]

I do not want to hardcode a width with `.frame(maxWidth: 50` on the Buttons Label Text.
It should just take as much space as possible, after that truncating the text (`.truncationMode`)

How can this be done **without** `GeometryReader` so that the result looks like:

[image]

**Update**

As suggested, XCode is checked latest 13.2 on macOS 11.6

Comment: Works fine here. Xcode 13.2 / macOS 12.1

Comment: without the .frame(maxWidth:50) ?
I am on Version 13.0 (13A233)

Comment: Yes, just copy-pasted your code snapshot in body as-is.

Comment: Ok XCode Upgrade started, thanks for checking.

Comment: Ok, it is not an XCode Issue. With 13.2 the button is not compressed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be related to known issues with **macOS**.

Only solution is, to create a custom `ButtonStyle` and apply the necessary restrictions there:

```swift
struct MacOSFixedButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .truncationMode(.middle)
            .lineLimit(1)
    }
}

extension View {
    func fixedMacOSButton(
    ) -> some View {
        self.buttonStyle(
            MacOSFixedButtonStyle()
        )
    }
}
```

Applied via:

```swift
Button("to long to read it and to put it in a view", action: {})
.fixedMacOSButton()
```